# How to set a class attribute to a Symfony form input with an attribut from entity linked

Tags: forms, input, attributes, symfony, symfony-forms

I have in my form a "beds" attribute, an entity linked to another "bedroom".
I would like for each input to add a class with the id of the linked entity "bedroom".

```
$form->add('beds', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'DamiasResaBundle:Bed',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
                  ->orderBy('b.id', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'id',
    'label' => 'lits ',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' =>true,
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => function ($bed) {
            return $bed->getBedroom()->getId();
        }
     ),
 ))
```

I have two problems:

1. 'attr' => array('class'=>'test) return a class attribut in the div  containing the input, not a class attribut in the input.
2. This previous code does not work and returns:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 358.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using checkboxes.
Your code seems ok, and since you use query_builder, the values should be a Bed Entity. Note that `attr` is not mentioned in the [EntityType documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html), and I think you need to use `choice_attr` instead.

Can you try this. I'm not sure if it will work or not:

```
$form->add('beds', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'DamiasResaBundle:Bed',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
                    ->orderBy('b.id', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'id',
    'label' => 'lits ',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' =>true,
    'choice_attr' => function ($val) {
            return ['class' => $val->getId()];
    },
))
```

Let us know the results.

Comment: Thanks, your solution match!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to [customize form rendering](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html)
2. Previous code doesn't work because you're trying to pass Closure object instead of string value. `attr` array is used as field attributes, so it must contain only string values (or objects with `__toString()` method).

Answer (score 0):

For EntityType it would rather look like this:

```
$form->add('beds', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'DamiasResaBundle:Bed',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
                    ->orderBy('b.id', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'id',
    'label' => 'lits ',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' =>true,
    'choice_attr' => function (Bed $bed, $key, $index) {
            return ['class' => $bed->getBedroom()->getId();];
    },
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since choice_attr seems not to be working anymore, I am writing another solution. I wasn't able to set attribute (exactly "min") directly from formBuilder. I managed to add it with help of js. I simply searched element by ID given by formBuilder and added atribute.

Inspect your form in browser element inspector and find id.

```
<div id="form_deadLine">
   <input type="date" id="form_deadLine_date" name="form[deadLine][date]" required="required" value="2020-02-20"/>
</div>
```

Id you wanna look for in my case is form_deadLine_date.

Then you wanna connect .js file to you twig template and write there simple script.

```
const form = document.getElementById('form_deadLine_date');
if(form){
    form.setAttribute("min", "2020-01-02")
}
```

then my code looks like:

```
<div id="form_deadLine">
   <input type="date" id="form_deadLine_date" name="form[deadLine][date]" required="required" value="2020-02-20"/>
</div>
```